# PhpStorm, issue when autocomplete functions declared multiple times (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, autocomplete, phpstorm

I have a little issue with Phpstorm when i use autocomplete.

The issue occurs with some Wordpress functions like :

[image]

After typing enter, i get :

[image]

Whereas i would like this result :

[image]

With cursor inside pararenthes and not after

I searched for 1h in settings, in documentation, on the web. I don't understant how to get there :/

Edit:

In fact, the function is declared three times :

[image]

Code for others declarations :

```
/**
 * @ignore
 */
function esc_attr() {}
```

Comment: Please show how that `esc_attr` function is defined. ATM such behaviour is applied if function has no parameters (no parameters = no need to be inside brackets). Based on your screenshot is has no parameters indeed. As long as there is at least one parameter cursor will be placed inside `()` after completion.

Comment: It's a wordpress function : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_attr On the other side this function is defined three time in wordpress source, only one have a parameter. How PhpStorm choose the good declaration ?

Comment: In all cases, i have exactly same problem with javascript functions like jquery addClass : https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Comment: I have enabled wordpress integration option : no difference :/

Comment: But you are right with an other wordpress function like get_post(), no problem, cursor go inside parenthesis.

Comment: Don't mix different languages -- each language implemented differently. For JavaScript you may *possibly* solve it by defining debug and release versions of jQuery and fetching the documentation (all done via JavaScript Libraries functionality).

Comment: About `esc_attr` in WordPress -- I have no clue why a function would be declared 3 times ... I'm not WP user but can you disable other 2 declarations (e.g. delete those files if they should not be there, or maybe mark them as Plain Text (via right click on them in Project View))? Or maybe commenting out those functions will do the job? Accordingly to your link such function should be defined in `wp-includes/formatting.php` file. In any case: I cannot explain how IDE selects what declaration is more correct in such weird case.

Comment: So i don't understand why but now, it works... Only declaration from formatting.php is used... Perhaps it's a setting i have modifed, perhap it was a bug... I don't know...

Comment: With PhpStorm 9, the issue came back... Finally, i used your solution and i marked the two files as plain text. If anyone have a better solution, I am all ears.